# WooCommerce: Checkout expiration not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've a website with WooCommerce installed. On my website I'm using CRED to allow my users to create products in my Shop (so they need to pay for this via the WooCommerce checkout).

When I fill out the CRED Toolset form now and press "Pay to create product", I'm getting redirected directly to the WooCommerce checkout.

When I close the page now (without continuing the payment) and come back 2 days later, the checkout is still there with the "product" in it. Because I don't want this, I've added this function here to clean the checkout after 2 hours but I've tried it and it don't works (the checkout is still available after days):

```
/**
 * Checkout and cart expiring
 */
add_filter( 'wc_session_expiring', 'wc_session_expiring' );
function wc_session_expiring( $seconds ) {
    return 60 * 60 * 1;
}

/**
 * Checkout and cart expired
 */
add_filter( 'wc_session_expiration', 'wc_session_expired' );
function wc_session_expired( $seconds ) {
    return 60 * 60 * 2;
}
```

So what can I do to clean the checkout after 2 hours waiting for the user to press the "Pay now" button?

Comment: Where is Loic? The master of WooCommerce :(

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Oh how nice :o no problem!

Comment: You should try to rename your function differently may be (not using the hook name), maybe like `filter_session_expiring` and `filter_session_expired`… Now I really don't know why this is not working…

Comment: Maybe it's not working because I've remove the cart page by removing the permalink under the WooCommerce settings? I just have the checkout page and not a cart. Maybe thats why it's not working? And because of the function names: Normally it should work because the filter always sees the first string as hook name and the last as function name. I did this a lot of times and this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Warning: Sorry but you should not use the hook name for the function name as there is a lot of hooks which names are also used by Wordpress and Woocommerce on core functions… So you should really avoid that.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Okay! But this might not be the solution why the expiration don't works, right?

Comment: *Left Center* **Right !**

Comment: Okay, so I'll forget this. I mean it should be no problem. When the customer creates a new product, the cart will be cleared anyway. So I'll see this as a feature and not as a bug.