# Remove applied coupons when user leaves the checkout page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website using WordPress and Woocommerce with a checkout page (mysite.com/checkout) where you can enter a promo code and get a discount on a produc. Is it possible to reset the coupon once the user leaves the checkout page and goes to a different page (shop, cart, ...)?

Comment: Hi there, some feed back on the answer below should be appreciated. As a new user please [**take the quick tour *(30 seconds)***](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), that explains basically how StackOverFlow works. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will remove applied coupons if customer leaves the checkout page:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_remove_coupons' );
function custom_remove_coupons(){
    // Get applied coupons
    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

    // We remove applied coupons outside checkout page
    if ( ! is_checkout() && sizeof($applied_coupons) > 0 ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_coupons();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hey Loic, I realy need your help please :( can you checkout this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637806/woocommerce-checkout-expiration-not-working